# How do I separate my discord.py balance for different servers?

Tags: python, json, discord.py

My discord.py bot has an economy system in it, and you can get coins, but everyones balance(coin amount) connects to every server. Here is my code that deals with the .json

```
async def oAcc(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["bal"] = 100

    with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
    return True

async def get_bank_data():
    with open("bank.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    return users
```

How do I change this up so each server has a different "database".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always just nest your `users` dictionary within a server object and keep them all separate in the same file.

```py
import json

# reading
def get_bank_data(server_name):
    with open("bank.json", "r") as f:
        database = json.load(f)
        users = database.get(server_name, {})
    return users

# writing
def put_bank_data(server_name, users):
    with open("bank.json", "r") as f:
        database = json.load(f)
    database[server_name] = users
    with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(database, f)

server_name = "test_server"
server2_name = "test_server2"
user_id = '101'


users = get_bank_data(server_name)
users2 = get_bank_data(server2_name)
users[user_id] = {}
users[user_id]['bal'] = 100
users2[user_id] = {}
users2[user_id]['bal'] = 200
put_bank_data(server_name, users)
put_bank_data(server2_name, users2)

users_get = get_bank_data(server_name)
print(users_get[user_id]['bal'])

users2_get = get_bank_data(server2_name)
print(users2_get[user_id]['bal'])
```

Also, note I didn't use `async`. There's not much reason to make a function asynchronous when you don't use `await` within it. Check out this article if you want to see how you can speed up file io asynchronously, because as is you're not changing anything. https://www.twilio.com/blog/working-with-files-asynchronously-in-python-using-aiofiles-and-asyncio

Comment: Ok I think im using this info wrong, but when I try to do this, I get a KeyError and it just sends the server id(i changed server name to server id just in case, hope that wasnt the problem)

Comment: My apologies I didn't test this with a complete example. I've provided you with one that works that should automatically correct some potential pitfalls with KeyErrors.

Comment: Ty Ty Ty, Ive been trying to figure this out for literally 2 days almost straight. I didn't think about making the servers apart of the get database lol